# WebDriver ImplicitlyWait fails on TeamCity Server

Tags: c#, selenium, teamcity

We are developing some functional tests using Selenium 2 framework on a FireFox 10 environment and we are in trouble with this special functionality:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

We are trying to setup the implicitly wait time to avoid sleep statements into our page objects. We we run the tests local or using a remote web driver everything works flawlessly, but when executing inside the TeamCity 7.0.4 server we got this unexpected modal:

```
 SetUp method failed. SetUp : System.InvalidOperationException : Modal dialog present (UnexpectedAlertOpen)  
 at ... [Stack trace] ...
```

Unfortunately we don't have access to see what modal is really showing up. If we turn back using sleep timers in place of the driver configuration, everything works.

Obs: We are sure that the TeamCity environment is setup just like in our local machines. Including the FireFox version.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a screenshot just before where it fails with that message. You'll then see what the modal dialog is.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but we have already tried without success. Again, without the Implicitly configuration, we can take screenshots.

Comment: Tried running the tests under the NUnit GUI on the CI Server? Have you also tried replicating the setup locally? I.e Setup teamcity on your own PC, see if it does the same thing. Are there any differences between your PC and the CI server? Sure that the CI server AND your PC both have Firefox 10? Does it happen with other drivers? (Chrome, specifically)

Comment: Hello Arran, we have tried to run under the Chrome environment without success. But your consideration is very useful, we will setup a local TC server and try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can inspect teamcity build log, trace the command which is triggering the test and run the same command from a command prompt on the same agent machine manually. This way you should be able to see the modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Start TeamCity Agent as normal process under your account (and not windows service) and wait what kind of dialog you will see.